# Does message_filters work with custom messages?

Tags: c++, ros

I'm trying to build a message_filter for a custom message and I'm getting this error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::MessageEvent >
>   ::MessageEvent(const ros::MessageEvent > >&, bool)’ 
>   Event my_event(event, nonconst_force_copy || event.nonConstWillCopy());

I don't get this issue when I'm using a `std_msgs message`. Is this an issue with message_filters or how I'm generating the messages?

**Note:** my custom message is `world2local::object_decription`

Comment: Message filters work definitely with custom messages. Are you sure that your message type has been generated as well as you have included them correctly in your code? Would be best if you post a minimal example of your project. Also: post ROS version and OS system!

Comment: The problem has been solved - I forgot to change the type of the message_filter to fit the custom message type. Thanks for your help however!